# AngularJS catch input validation inside in directive and set class to parent element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create the directive, in which I need to catch the validity input inside directive and then transfer to the parent element.

Simple directive

```
<my-input type="text" placeholder="Simple placeholder" name="Name of input"></my-input>
```

Template of simple directive

```
<div class="my-input-wrap" ng-class="getInputClass(inputModel)">
    <input type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-model="inputModel" />
</div><!-- ./my-input-wrap -->
```

Simple directive code

```
angular.module('angular-bootstrap')
    .directive('myInput', MyInputDirective);

function MyInputDirective() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            label: '@',
            name: '@',
            type: '@',
            placeholder: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'my-input.html',
        controller: MyInputController,
        controllerAs: 'myInput',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, NgModelController) {

            // NgModelController get validation only directive not input element inside directive

            scope.getInputClass = function() {
                console.log('INV' + NgModelController.$invalid);
                console.log('DIRT' + NgModelController.$dirty);
                return {
                    required: NgModelController.$invalid && NgModelController.$dirty
                };
            };

        }
    };
}

function MyInputController($scope) {
    //...
}
```

I need in directive find input and his validation ($invalid, $dirty, ...) and set class to parent element, I do not want to use the form inside.

How can I be notified when the validity of a input changes?